# Discrete geometric asian option, analytic vs MC

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, exotics, asian-option

I am attempting to price a discrete geometric Asian option using both the closed form formula (can be found in section 3.2.2 of 'Monte Carlo methods in Financial Engineering' by Glasserman) and an MC estimator. I obtain different results, 0.2170 for the analytic and ~0.2117 for the mc estimator. I do not think it is an issue with two few trajectories. My parameters are the following:

nb_time_steps: 1001 (t0 = 0.0, T = 1.0), vol: 0.2, r: 0.05, spot: 1.0.

Please find below my code:

```
def bs_vanilla(tau, stock, K, r, div_yield, vol, *args):
  normal = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(0.0, 1.0)
  d_minus = (torch.log(stock / K) + (r - div_yield - vol**2 / 2) * tau) / (vol * torch.sqrt(tau))
  d_plus = d_minus + vol * torch.sqrt(tau)
  i1 = stock * torch.exp(-tau * div_yield) * (normal.cdf(d_plus)).to(device)
  i2 = -torch.exp(-r * tau) * K * normal.cdf(d_minus).to(device)
  return i1 + i2

def bs_discrete_geometric_asian(nb_steps, T, stock, K, r, vol):
  time = torch.linspace(0, T, nb_steps, device=device)
  inv_idx = torch.arange(time.size(0)-1, -1, -1, device=device).long()
  indices = torch.arange(0, nb_steps, device=device)
  mean_t = time.mean()
  vol_mean = ((indices*2+1)*time[inv_idx]).sum()*vol**2/(nb_steps**2*mean_t)
  div_yield = (1.0/2.0)*vol**2 - (1.0/2.0)*vol_mean
  return bs_vanilla(mean_t, stock, K, r, div_yield, torch.sqrt(vol_mean))

def mc_discrete_geom(nb_traj, nb_steps, T, K, r, vol, s_0):
  normal = torch.distributions.normal.Normal(0.0, 1.0)
  dt = torch.tensor(T/(nb_steps-1), device=device)
  running_stock = torch.ones(nb_traj, device=device)*s_0
  running_stock_geom_mean = torch.ones(nb_traj, device=device)*s_0
  samples = normal.sample((nb_traj, nb_steps-1)).to(device)
  for t in range(1, nb_steps):
    running_stock = running_stock*torch.exp((r-(1.0/2.0)*vol**2)*dt+vol*torch.sqrt(dt)*samples[:, t-1])
    running_stock_geom_mean = running_stock_geom_mean *   copy_tensor(running_stock)**(1/(nb_steps-1))
  payoff_geom = torch.exp(-r * T) * torch.clamp(running_stock_geom_mean - K, min=0)
  return payoff_geom.mean(dim=0)

print(mc_discrete_geom(100000, 1001, torch.tensor(1.0, device=device), torch.tensor(0.8), torch.tensor(0.05, device=device), torch.tensor(0.2, device=device), torch.tensor(1.0, device=device)))
print(bs_discrete_geometric_asian(1001, torch.tensor(1.0, device=device), torch.tensor(1.0, device=device), torch.tensor(0.8, device=device), torch.tensor(0.05, device=device), torch.tensor(0.2)))
```

Comment: Quick question - may I ask why you're using (what I assume is) pytorch for this?

Comment: I am working on an application of neural networks in finance.

Comment: You obtain $ C_0^{BS} = 0.2170 $ and $C_0^{MC} = 0.2117 $  which is just a difference of 0.005 and you think your program is wrong. Why?

Comment: The relative difference is around 2.5% which I find is very large.

Comment: Moreover, the MC price has converged, more trajectories won't get it closer to the analytic price.

Comment: If it's always that value you might want to check the seed; what's the strike for this option?

Comment: the strike is K=0.8